# Ajax validation in success fail always get EmptyObject true

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax method get who call my controller. Into success function it get two arrays: `eventos.asignados` and `eventos.noAsignados`

Problem is validation always comes true, because it always send me alert, as you can see there:
[image]

can someone explain me why it pass validation if my array is not empty?

**AJAX CALL:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Agenda/GetTareasCalendario/",
        data: {
            //data there
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (eventos) {

            refreshCalendarEvents(eventos.asignados);
            addEvents(eventos.noAsignados, true);

            if ($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados && eventos.noAsignados)) {
                alert('No se han encontrado resultados con los filtros seleccionados.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `eventos.asignados && eventos.noAsignados` evaluates to `eventos.noAsignados`. So you essentially end up doing `$.isEmptyObject(eventos.noAsignados)`, i.e. you are only checking whether one of the properties is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if` conditions like below to check for empty objects one by one

**Try this:**

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados) && $.isEmptyObject(eventos.noAsignados)) {
    alert('No se han encontrado resultados con los filtros seleccionados.');
}
```